# React native maps draggable marker onDragEnd position?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I just started using react native maps~0.22.1, and I am having trouble acquiring the draggable marker onDragend new position;
I followed the documentation even though it is a bit vag, but the result is undefined;

Here is my code:

```
<Marker
        ref={(ref) => { this.marker = ref; }}
        draggable
        onDragEnd={(t, map, coords) => this.setDestination(coords)}
        coordinate={destination}
        position={destination}
        centerOffset={{ x: -18, y: -60 }}
        anchor={{ x: 0.69, y: 1 }}
        pinColor={COLOR.marker}
        onDragStart={() => this.setMarkerPosition()}
      />
```

setDestination function:

```
setDestination(coords) {
    const { destination } = this.props;
    const lat = coords.lat();
    const long = coords.lng();
    console.log('seperate:', lat, long);
    console.log('destina:', coords);
    this.props
      .dispatch($setDestination(coords.lat(), coords.lng()))
      .catch((error) => this.props.dispatch(Activity.$toast('failure', error.message)));

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isVisible: !prevState.isVisible,
      destination: destination[0].fullAddress,
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> onDragEnd={(e) => {console.log('dragEnd', e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}}